# Ubuntu, codeigniter, mssql

Tags: php, sql-server-2008, ubuntu-12.04, codeigniter-2

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 for my apache and php and as framework I am using codeigniter. some I need to work with MSSQL server database on my project but couldn't make it work.

part of phpinfo()

[image: Part of my phpinfo]

and I am getting error like following 
[image]

and my database.php file is

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;
$db['default']['hostname'] = DB_LOCATION;
$db['default']['username'] = DB_USER;
$db['default']['password'] = DB_PASSWORD;
$db['default']['database'] = DB_NAME;
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mssql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';<br />
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE
```

Comment: Are you using sqlsrv driver?? also please provide your database  configuration.

Comment: Where's the lines of code where you actually try to establish the connection?